# Unresolved external symbol _printf referenced in function _main

Tags: c

I'm a complete newbie at C programming and I was writing a program and it started throwing the below error:

> error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol_printf referenced in function_main

I'm using the C compiler.

My code is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int EarthWeight;    // Weight on earth

    float Mercurypercent, Venuspercent,
    Marspercent, Jupiterpercent, Saturnpercent, Neptunepercent; // wieght percents

    float Mercurywieght, Venusweight, Marsweight, Jupiterweight, Saturnweight, Neptuneweight; // wieght outputs

    Mercurypercent = 0.378; // percent values of all the planets
    Venuspercent = 0.907;
    Marspercent = 0.377;
    Jupiterpercent = 2.36;
    Saturnpercent = 0.889;
    Neptunepercent = 1.12;  

    printf("what is the Weight of the person on earth? "); // Grabs the weight on earth
    scanf("%d", &EarthWeight);

    Mercurywieght = EarthWeight * Mercurypercent;
    Venusweight = EarthWeight * Venuspercent;
    Marsweight = EarthWeight * Marspercent;
    Jupiterweight = EarthWeight * Jupiterpercent;
    Saturnweight = EarthWeight * Saturnpercent;
    Neptuneweight = EarthWeight * Neptunepercent;

    Printf("Your Weight on Earth is: %d\n", EarthWeight);
    Printf("Your Weight on Mercury is: %f\n", Mercurywieght);
    Printf("Your Weight on Venus is: %f\n", Venusweight);
    Printf("Your Weight on Mars is: %f\n", Marsweight);
    Printf("Your Weight on Jupiter is: %f\n", Jupiterweight);
    Printf("Your Weight on Saturn is: %f\n", Saturnweight);
    Printf("Your Weight on Neptune is: %f\n", Neptuneweight);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When posting error messages, make sure you **copy & paste** the error message, as-is. I strongly suspect that your error message looked a *bit* different than what you posted (there is *definitely* a space after "symbol" and "function"), so the real issue might be "hidden".

Comment: You should also get errors/warnings about implicit declaration of `Printf` ... do not ignore any of your compiler messages

Comment: Maybe you should just replace `Printf` by `printf`. In C symbols (and keywords too) are case sensitive.

Answer (score 5):

C is case-sensitive and you're calling `Printf` instead of `printf`.

C is also very typo-sensitive, and you have some in your questions and variable name, so beware...

Comment: Sure 'Printf()' is wrong, but why does linker error message flag up '_printf', ie lower-case 'p'?

Comment: ^^ Hmm... you may be right.  OP may not have copypasta the error message and so 'hidden' the problem when typing into an editor.   Whatever - you deserved your upboat anyway - I didn't spot the typo:(

Comment: I also getting that error when trying to link a test program. The following webpage might help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2019?view=msvc-170